# Django authentication - wrong redirect url to login page

Tags: django, redirect, django-authentication

When a user is not logged I'm trying to enter areas of site for authenticated users only I should be redirected to my login site with `?next=` and here my LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL from settings. But instead of `/users/login` in my address bar `/accounts/login` is displayed. What should I change to get the right url ?

settings :

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/user/profile/'
```

project's urls :

```
import accounts.urls as regUrls

urlpatterns = patterns("",
                        (...)                     
                        (r'^user/', include(regUrls)),                       
                        )
```

accounts application urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^profile/$', profile_edit , name='user_profile'),
                       url(r'^friends_list/$', friends_list),
                       (r'', include('accounts.auth_urls')),
                       )
```

and accounts auth_urls.py (which are simply urls for contrib.auth) :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
                           url(r'^login/$',
                               auth_views.login,
                               {'template_name': 'user/login_logout_register/login.html'},
                               name='auth_login'),
                           url(r'^logout/$',
                               auth_views.logout,
                               {'template_name': 'user/login_logout_register/logout.html'},
                               name='auth_logout'),                     
                           url(r'^password/change/$',
                               auth_views.password_change,
                               {'template_name': 'user/login_logout_register/password_change_form.html'},
                               name='auth_password_change'),
                           url(r'^password/change/done/$',
                               auth_views.password_change_done,
                               {'template_name': 'user/login_logout_register/password_change_done.html'},
                               name='auth_password_change_done'),                      
                           url(r'^password/reset/$',
                               auth_views.password_reset,
                               {'template_name': 'user/login_logout_register/password_reset_form.html',
                               'email_template_name': 'user/login_logout_register/password_reset_email.html'},
                               name='auth_password_reset'),                     
                           url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
                               auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
                               {'template_name': 'user/login_logout_register/password_reset_confirm.html'},
                               name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),                     
                           url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
                               auth_views.password_reset_complete,
                               {'template_name': 'user/login_logout_register/password_reset_complete.html'},
                               name='auth_password_reset_complete'),                     
                           url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
                               auth_views.password_reset_done,
                               {'template_name': 'user/login_logout_register/password_reset_done.html'},
                               name='auth_password_reset_done'),
                           )
```

If i should paste anytning more, just tell me.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to set the [`LOGIN_URL`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_URL) in settings as well:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/user/login'
```

Comment: now I got : `http://domain/user/profile/?next=/user/profile/%3Fnext%3D/user/profile/%253Fnext%253D/user/profile/%25253...` :/

Comment: The LOGIN_URL should have been "/user/login" not "/user/profile" .. missed that in your question.  Updated above.

Comment: In my case, specifying just the name of the login view also worked: `LOGIN_URL = 'login'`.