# Django auth registration views login redirect

Tags: django

I'm using Django's auth views. I didn't want the 'accounts/' in my registration urls, so I changed them from this:

```
accounts/password_change/ [name='password_change'] 
accounts/login/ [name='login']
```

To:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

Now, when a user who is not signed in attempts to access this view, it
redirects to:

`127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/password_change/`

How to I get it to redirect to this instead?

`127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/password_change/`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367757/django-authentication-wrong-redirect-url-to-login-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting LOGIN_URL in your settings.py file:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

Comment: awesome, no worries! Make sure to accept the answer so others can see it as well :)